# annotation with a table referred to by content_type + object_id in DjangoORM

Tags: sql, django, django-models, django-orm

So issue is I need to filter by title field that in many others tables.

class `Model` uses `contenttypes` framework in django. It refers to several tables that have a `title` field (field I want to filter by)

```py
class Model(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ContentType,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        limit_choices_to={'model__in': ('model1', 'model2', 'model3', 'model4', 'model5')},
    )
    object_id = models.CharField(max_length=36)
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Every table that has the `title` field has `GenericRelation(Model, related_query_name='animals')`

```
class Cat(models.Model): # and etc Dog, Cow, Bear
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    myfield = GenericRelation(Model, related_name_query='animals')
```

First I Tried `Model.objects.annotate(title=F('animals__title'))`. But for some reasons it does not work for me because it joins only one table. It makes sence because anyway I need to handle these strings with `Coalesce`.

So I figured it out by create my own SQL query but I cannot convert it to DjangoORM

here is the query

```sql
SELECT
    "mm"."id",
    COALESCE("Cat"."title", "Dog"."title", "Cow"."title", "Bird"."title", "Bear"."title") AS "title"
FROM
    "Model" AS "mm"
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    "Cat" AS "Cat" ON ("mm"."object_id" = "Cat"."id")
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    "Dog" AS "Dog" ON ("mm"."object_id" = "Dog"."id")
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    "Cow" AS "Cow" ON ("mm"."object_id" = "Cow"."id")
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    "Bird" AS "Bird" ON ("mm"."object_id" = "Bird"."id")
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    "Bear" AS "Bear" ON ("mm"."object_id" = "Bear"."id");
```

And it perfectly works for me. But I have been strugling to convert it to django orm.

I tried to do subquery using `queryset.extra(select={'title': 'SELECT...'})` but for some reason it fetchs only Dogs table but not others (same behavior when I try `.filter(animals__title='foo')`)

Comment: @Selcuk `limit_choices_to` does not make any sence for me in this case I just wrote it as a hint

Comment: Sure. What I meant was your SQL only `JOIN`s 5 models, but there is no way that Django could know that you are only interested in those 5, and it can't use `limit_choices_to` as a hint.

Comment: @Selcuk hmmm, but these 5 models have `GenericRelation(Model, related_query_name='elements')`. But if I do `Model.objects.filter(elements__title='foo')` and see query it fetchs only one table but not 4 others